# How do I access a second existing commit from a previous commit?

Tags: git

Let's say I made 3 commits, for the same text file called *'planets.txt'*.

The first commit, stores the message:

> - No planet discovered

The second commit:

> - No planet discovered
> - Mars (Found!)

The third commit:

> - No planet discovered
> - Mars (Found!)
> - Jupiter (Found!)

Suppose I go back to the first version of the commit, and make a change to the file by adding the following text:

> - No planet discovered
> - planet earth wiped out by aliens

This represents an alternative reality for this short narrative that I created. And in this case, I did the whole process as a `git add .` and git `commit -m 'new reality, humanity decimated before finding planets'`.

Why when I go back to the **master**, run `git log`, enter the first commit and run a second `git log`, I can't see a commit with the message *'new reality, humanity decimated before finding planets'*?

Did the file not get saved? If so, how do I access it?

Comment: How did you “go back to the first version”?

Comment: What if you do `git log --all --oneline`, do you see the commit then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Git, an alternate reality is a *branch*. The reality exists on that branch.

I'll demonstrate. First I'll build up your three commits in series, on master (the default branch):

```
$ echo "no planet discovered" > a.txt
$ git add a.txt; git commit -m'start'
$ echo "Mars found" >> a.txt
$ git commit -a -m'mars'
$ echo "Jupiter found" >> a.txt
$ git commit -a -m'jupiter'
$ git log --oneline
d71d5d9 (HEAD -> master) jupiter
81c1cba mars
4adf736 start
```

Fine, so far so good. Now I'll go back to the first commit and branch off from there:

```
$ git branch alternateReality 4adf
$ git checkout alternateReality
$ echo "earth wiped out" >> a.txt
$ git commit -a -m'wiped'
```

I'm still on the `alternateReality` branch. Let's look at the file:

```
$ cat a.txt
no planet discovered
earth wiped out
```

But meanwhile, the original reality is still sitting on the other branch, `master`, and I can see it by switching to that branch:

```
$ git checkout master
$ cat a.txt
no planet discovered
Mars found
Jupiter found
```

You can have both, one on each branch, but you can't see both at once. They are alternate realities. To see the other one, you have to switch branches.

(In real Git life, the purpose of alternate realities would be to bring them together into the *one* reality eventually. You would do that by *merging* the branches. But that is not what you asked, as far as I can tell. These two branches would not be easily merged because they are *conflicting* alternate realities.)

Comment: Hi @matt, I Have one more question... In the case of that alternative reality that I created using the codes described in my question. In that case that change was lost forever, right? Or is there a way to access it?

Comment: Nothing in Git is ever lost unless you deliberately choose to destroy it. If you did it the way I did it, the branch lives on and therefore all commits on that branch live on. You would gave to deliberately delete the branch to destroy the branch explicitly, and Git would loudly resist you doing that if it meant the commits would be destroyed.